# looking for the symbol :=

Tags: symbols

I am looking for the symbol := and the symbol ::=

the first one means "expressed as" (e.g. a sentence A is *expressed as* a juxtaposition of words bcd) and the second one means "defined as", in various applications of logic and language theory. in Linux, typing := one after one (in kile or lyx) causes vertical misalignment of the characters. I expect the center point between two dots of : and the center line through the two lines of = be on the same line, but often = is positioned too high, and also the space between them is too large, and a negetive space of -0.1 em does not look good.

Anyone like to help, telling me where to find these two symbols?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\coloneqq\quad\Coloneqq
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah, i did not know of the mathtools package.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) at page 31 these symbols can also be obtained in this way (without include new packages)

`\mathrel{\mathop:}=` [image]

`\mathrel{\mathop:\mathop:}=` [image]

for the second add a negative `\hspace` to have the symbol more condensed:

`\mathrel{\mathop:\hspace{-.2em}\mathop:}=`

[image]

Comment: I'd say `\mathrel{\mathop:}\mathrel{\mathop:}=` because TeX inserts no space between consecutive relation symbols; or `\mathrel{\mathop:\!\mathop:}=` because TeX inserts a thin space between consecutive operators (no need to guess the exact amount).

Comment: @egreg I know it's almost 4 years now, but does `\mathrel{:=}` do the job? (for the first symbol).

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf No; you need `\mathrel{:}=` or the spacing would be wrong; on the other hand the colon will be misaligned.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I'll rollback to the previous suggestion; though I couldn't manage to see the difference at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

You can make these symbols using `txfonts/pxfonts` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
$\coloneqq \Coloneqq$
\end{document}
```

Note: Also try loading `texdoc symbols-a4` in command-line for list of symbols.

Comment: this is what i was looking for : these symbols in math mode

Comment: Usual comment: this changes all the appearance of the document. Anyway, it's better `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, because these two packages cure some shortcomings of `txfonts`.